# Activity UI not refreshing after navigating up

Tags: java, android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I have three Activites: MainActivity (with a ListView), SettingsActivity and NoteActivity (to show notes). The MainActivity starts either the SettingsActivity or the NoteActivity.

When I press back (on the navigationbar of my phone) in the Settings or NoteActivity I go back to the MainActivity and `listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is called. The Listview refreshes and everything is working. 
When I press up (the back arrow in the toolbar of the Settings or NoteActivity) the same Methods are called but the Listview doesn't refresh.
This only happens when I navigate up and not when I navigate back.

The MainActivity is set as parent Activity in Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".settings.SettingsActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="de.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Also other UI Elements like the SwipeRefreshLayout are not working after navigating up. I've use the debugger to see a difference in the behaviour but in both cases the same methods are called.

Has anybody an idea where the problem is? Please tell if you need more code.

//Edit: some Code

The relevant code of my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Note> notes;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<Note> adapter;
    SwipeRefreshLayout srl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickFab(view);
            }
        });

        notes = NoteManager.Instance.getNotes(this);
        adapter = new NoteAdapter(this,notes);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                itemClickedAction(view, position, id);
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                return itemLongClickedAction(view, position, id);
            }
        });

        srl = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        srl.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                startSync();
            }
        });

        this.startSync();
    }

    private void startSync(){
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Start Sync");
        NoteManager.Instance.sync();
    }


    public void syncFinished(){
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Sync finished");
        this.datasetChanged();
        if(srl.isRefreshing()) {
            srl.setRefreshing(false);
        }

    }

    public void datasetChanged(){
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "DataSetChanged");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

The onDestroy-Method of my NoteActivity tells the NoteManager to call `mainActivity.datasetChanged()`. The method call is logged so the method must be called. It's working when pressing back but not when pressing up. In both cases I see the log.

Same for the SwipeRefresh Layout. The `startSync` and `syncFinished`-Methods are called. But the loading animation isn't stopping although `srl.setRefreshing(false)`is called. It seems to be a problem with the UI Elements.

--> different behaviour when calling the same methods

Comment: share your code as well.

Comment: where you have called listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I've added some Code. The notifyDataSetChanged is called when the other Activity is destroyed (onDestroy).

Answer (score 0):

> The onDestroy-Method of my NoteActivity tells the NoteManager to call mainActivity.datasetChanged(). The method call is logged so the method must be called. It's working when pressing back but not when pressing up. In both cases I see the log.

Try putting `mainActivity.datasetChanged()` in `onPause or onStop` instead.

Even better would be to start the NoteActivity with `startActivityForResult`.

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer (I cannot upvote yet). That didn't solve the problem. I don't think it has to do with the particular time when the methods are called, eg. the loading animation of the SwipeRefreshLayout is called from the MainActivity and is stopped (`srl.setRefreshing(false)`) from the MainActivity when I'm in the MainActivity but it doesn't stop. It works as long as I have not used the navigate up function. Same for the `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: My guess was, that onDestroy is not called when navigating with up. Have you tried startActivityForResult?